# No events detected! PAPI 7.1.0 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, events, processor, papi, preset

I am trying to use PAPI to check processor events for a college work, but it doesn't show any PAPI Preset Events when use `papi_avail -a`

After I've already installed libopenmpi-dev, papi-tools and PAPI 7.1.0, the output for `papi_avail -a` was:

```
Available PAPI preset and user defined events plus hardware information.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PAPI version             : 7.1.0.0
Operating system         : Linux 6.5.0-17-generic
Vendor string and code   : GenuineIntel (1, 0x1)
Model string and code    : 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz (140, 0x8c)
CPU revision             : 1.000000
CPUID                    : Family/Model/Stepping 6/140/1, 0x06/0x8c/0x01
CPU Max MHz              : 4700
CPU Min MHz              : 400
Total cores              : 8
SMT threads per core     : 2
Cores per socket         : 4
Sockets                  : 1
Cores per NUMA region    : 8
NUMA regions             : 1
Running in a VM          : no
Number Hardware Counters : 19
Max Multiplex Counters   : 384
Fast counter read (rdpmc): no
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

================================================================================
  PAPI Preset Events
================================================================================
    Name        Code    Deriv Description (Note)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Of 0 available events, 0 are derived.

No events detected!  Check papi_component_avail to find out why.
```

After this I used `papi_component_avail` and the output was:

```
Compiled-in components:
Name:   perf_event              Linux perf_event CPU counters
Name:   perf_event_uncore       Linux perf_event CPU uncore and northbridge
   \-> Disabled: No uncore PMUs or events found
Name:   sysdetect               System info detection component

Active components:
Name:   perf_event              Linux perf_event CPU counters
                                Native: 165, Preset: 0, Counters: 19
                                PMUs supported: ix86arch, perf, perf_raw, icl

Name:   sysdetect               System info detection component
                                Native: 0, Preset: 0, Counters: 0
```

So what I need to do to papi detects the processor events?
Thanks for any help!